# How to find the char value of an string in nth sequence of PHP string

Tags: php

I have a string which is like `00000100100` now I need to know what is the value of 6th char in the string. or 3rd and ....

How can I achieve this is PHP? I already tried like this but looks like not working as I am not getting anything back

```
<?php
$binocode = "00000000000000000000";

if(str_split($binocode, 3) == '0') echo "it is Zero";
if(str_split($binocode, 3) == '1') echo "it is One";
?>
```

Comment: I don't think you're getting anything back because the second parameter of `str_split(string, int)` is not the index, but rather how large the chunks should be when split. Thus you'll be getting back an array of many `'000'` in your given example.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily grab the char at a given position as follows:

```php
$string = '00000000000000000000';

// Not when accessing using this syntax, keys are zero-indexed, so char 1 = key 0
echo "Char 3: $string[2]";

echo "Char 6: $string[5]";

echo "Char 12: $string[11]";
```